# How to get centroids from Ball Tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

According to the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms), their `sklearn.neighbors.BallTree` class

> recursively divides the data into nodes defined by a centroid C and radius r, such that each point in the node lies within the hyper-sphere defined by C and r.

Is there a way, given a `BallTree` instance, to extract those centroids without recomputing them? The `get_arrays()` method exposes the radii and the datapoints contained by each node, but does not expose the centroids. In Euclidean space, one could easily compute centroids by averaging all of the datapoints in each node, but this becomes harder in other metrics. Furthermore, it doesn't seem necessary that a user should have to perform this computation if the `BallTree` instance has already done so internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last array in the result of the [`get_arrays` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.get_arrays) is the "node bounds" array, which contains the centroids:

> node_bounds : the [* x n_nodes x n_features] array containing the node bound information.  For ball tree, the first dimension is 1, and each row contains the centroid of the node. [...]

[[source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5fc67aeb092d636895b599921283221a68c7a2ad/sklearn/neighbors/_binary_tree.pxi.tp#L70)]

Comment: Good catch! I wonder why that explanation isn't offered in the main docs.